# Can't print actual values “request.getparameterValues” in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

When I'm Dispatching a JSP page through Servlet by the following code:

```
String[] UserList = ViewAllUserBasedOnRights(UserViewBy);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test/TestGetParameterValues.jsp?UserList="+UserList+"").forward(request, response);
```

And the JSP page shows "**[Ljava.lang.String;@8b3f2a**".

In this method "`ViewAllUserBasedOnRights();`" values are collect from my database and it will return either `NULL` or a set of `Strings`.

Details:

```
public static String[] ViewAllUserBasedOnRights(String UserName) throws Exception{
                String[] retVal = null;
                Connection con=null;
                try{
                con= DatabaseConnectionManager.getDatabaseConnectionManager().getConnection(DatabaseConnectionManager.EAGRO_APP_DB);
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                Statement stmt1 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                String SQLStringCount = "....";
                try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLStringCount)){
                    int count = -1;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("COUNT"));
                    }
                    if(count > 0){
                        String SQLString =".....";

                    System.out.println("SQLString: "+SQLString);
                    try(ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(SQLString)){
                        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                        while(rs1.next()){
                            stringList.add(rs1.getString("USER_NAME"));
                        }
                        String[] temp = new String[stringList.size()];
                        retVal = (String[]) stringList.toArray(temp);
                        con.commit();
                        rs1.close();

                    }catch(SQLException e){
                        try{
                            if(con!=null)
                                extracted(con);
                            }catch(Exception ex){}
                        }
                }
            }catch(SQLException e){
                try{
                    if(con!=null)
                        extracted(con);
                    }catch(Exception ex){}
                }

            }catch(SQLException e){
                try{
                    if(con!=null)
                        extracted(con);
                    }catch(Exception ex){}
                }
            return retVal;
        }
```

Code of my JSP page, its very simple just I catch the values and print:

```
<%
String[] UserList;
UserList = (String[])request.getParameterValues("UserList");
for(int i = 0; i < UserList.length; i++){
%>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" align="center"><%=i+1%>
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" align="left" ><%=UserList[i]%>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommonded to use scriptlet in jsp.You can use jstl tags

```
<c:forEach items="UserList" var="temp">
   ${temp}
</c:forEach>
```

and import `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

before using to this

Answer (score 0):

From your code,  I see that you are creating an `ArrayList` when iterating `ResultSet` and then creating String array to send values.

As, You are forwarding request to JSP you should send `ArrayList` as request object to JSP and then iterate it there.

Return `ArrayList` (`return stringList;`) from `ViewAllUserBasedOnRights(UserViewBy)` method instead of `String` Array.

When Forwarding page:

```
List<String> userList = ViewAllUserBasedOnRights(UserViewBy);
request.setAttribute("userList", userList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test/TestGetParameterValues.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
<%
List<String> userList;
int nSize=0;
userList = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("userList");
if(userList!=null){
nSize= userList.size();
}

for(int i = 0; i < nSize; i++){
%>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" align="center"><%=i+1%>
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" align="left" ><%=userList.get(i)%>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got the solution, I have edited on my Servlet and JSP page below

Changed in Servlet:

```
String[] UserList = ViewAllUserBasedOnRights(UserViewBy);
request.setAttribute("userList", UserList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/test/TestGetParameterValues.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Changed in JSP page:

```
<%
String[] UserList = null;
if(request.getAttribute("UserList")!= null){
UserList = new String[((String[])request.getAttribute("UserList")).length];
UserList = ((String[])request.getAttribute("UserList"));
}
for(int i = 0; i < UserList.length; i++){
%>
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;" align="center"><%=i+1%>
    </td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;" align="left" ><%=UserList[i]%>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```